# Space in column name is throwing exception while parquet is used for compression

Tags: apache-spark, hive, cloudera, parquet

I am getting below error while inserting the data into a table of parquet format with column name having space.

Used Hive client of Cloudera version

CREATE TABLE testColumNames( `First Name` string) stored as parquet;
insert into testColumNames select 'John Smith';

Is there any workaround to solve this issue? We got this error from Spark 2.3 code as well.

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field ended by ';': expected ';' but got 'name' at line 1:   optional binary first name
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getHiveRecordWriter(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:248)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.createBucketForFileIdx(FileSinkOperator.java:583)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.createBucketFiles(FileSinkOperator.java:527)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:636)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:98)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:157)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:497)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:170)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:459)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1924)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field ended by ';': expected ';' but got 'name' at line 1:   optional binary first name
at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.check(MessageTypeParser.java:212)
at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addPrimitiveType(MessageTypeParser.java:185)
at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addType(MessageTypeParser.java:111)
at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addGroupTypeFields(MessageTypeParser.java:99)
at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.parse(MessageTypeParser.java:92)
at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.parseMessageType(MessageTypeParser.java:82)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriteSupport.getSchema(DataWritableWriteSupport.java:43)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriteSupport.init(DataWritableWriteSupport.java:48)
at parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:310)
at parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:287)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.<init>(ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.java:69)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat.getParquerRecordWriterWrapper(MapredParquetOutputFormat.java:134)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat.getHiveRecordWriter(MapredParquetOutputFormat.java:123)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getRecordWriter(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:260)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getHiveRecordWriter(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:245)
... 18 more

org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field ended by ';': expected ';' but got 'name' at line 1:   optional binary first name
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getHiveRecordWriter(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:248)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.createBucketForFileIdx(FileSinkOperator.java:583)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.createBucketFiles(FileSinkOperator.java:527)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.closeOp(FileSinkOperator.java:974)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:598)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:199)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:459)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1924)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field ended by ';': expected ';' but got 'name' at line 1:   optional binary first name
at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.check(MessageTypeParser.java:212)
at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addPrimitiveType(MessageTypeParser.java:185)
at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addType(MessageTypeParser.java:111)
at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addGroupTypeFields(MessageTypeParser.java:99)
at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.parse(MessageTypeParser.java:92)
at parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.parseMessageType(MessageTypeParser.java:82)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriteSupport.getSchema(DataWritableWriteSupport.java:43)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriteSupport.init(DataWritableWriteSupport.java:48)
at parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:310)
at parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:287)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.<init>(ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.java:69)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat.getParquerRecordWriterWrapper(MapredParquetOutputFormat.java:134)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat.getHiveRecordWriter(MapredParquetOutputFormat.java:123)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getRecordWriter(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:260)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getHiveRecordWriter(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:245)
... 16 more
```

Comment: Can you try ` `column name` ` - with back ticks

Comment: @bala Tried but no luck.

Comment: You are right.  While create works with back ticks, insert fails

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the below url:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-677

It seems this issue is not yet resolved.

Answer (score 1):

From Hive Doc https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL

> Table names and column names are case insensitive but SerDe and
> property names are case sensitive.
>
> In Hive 0.12 and earlier, only
> alphanumeric and underscore characters are allowed in table and column
> names.
>
> In Hive 0.13 and later, column names can contain any Unicode
> character (see HIVE-6013), however, dot (.) and colon (:) yield errors
> on querying, so they are disallowed in Hive 1.2.0 (see HIVE-10120).
> Any column name that is specified within backticks (`) is treated
> literally. Within a backtick string, use double backticks (``) to
> represent a backtick character. Backtick quotation also enables the
> use of reserved keywords for table and column identifiers.
>
> To revert
> to pre-0.13.0 behavior and restrict column names to alphanumeric and
> underscore characters, set the configuration property
> hive.support.quoted.identifiers to none. In this configuration,
> backticked names are interpreted as regular expressions. For details,
> see Supporting Quoted Identifiers in Column Names.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Synapse Analytics, we got this error when reading a table from dedicatep1, using pyspark function in a notebook:

```
%%pyspark    
import com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics    
<dataframe> = read.table.synapsesql("dedicatedp1.dbo.<tablename>")
```

... if the dedicatedp1 source table had SPACES in the columnnames.

The spaces in columnames was still a problem, even if we tried using pyspark function `withColumnRenamed`.

So, finally, we had to resolve this using SQL `SELECT ... INTO` in dedicatedp1, to copy the source table into another table, with the columns renamed to have underlines instead of spaces.

Since there were almost 700 columns involved, we used code to generate the column lines, for the SELECT/INTO ... because (yay) INFORMATION_SCHEMA is indeed usable in sql scripts for dedicatedp1:

```
select PYSPARK_CMD = 
    ', ['
    + c1.column_name 
    + '] as '
    + REPLACE(c1.column_name, ' ', '_')
from information_schema.columns   c1
where table_name = '<dedicatedp1 source table>'
order by ordinal_position
```